# Android - Custom background image

Tags: android, android-background

I want to change my app's background randomly. It's supposed to have a random image from its own folder as background. It works perfectly with some devices but with some of them doesn't. I wonder what could cause this inconsistency. Here is my random background generator class:

```
public class arkaplanGenerator {
public static int arkaplan(){
    int sonucArkaplan = 0;
    Random r = new Random();
    int sayi = r.nextInt(11);
    switch (sayi){
        case 0:
            sonucArkaplan = R.drawable.bavaria;
            break;
        case 1:
            sonucArkaplan = R.drawable.gorges;
            break;
        case 2:
            sonucArkaplan = R.drawable.more;
            break;
        case 3:
            sonucArkaplan = R.drawable.mountains;
            break;
        case 4:
            sonucArkaplan = R.drawable.pisa;
            break;
        case 5:
            sonucArkaplan = R.drawable.sea;
            break;
        case 6:
            sonucArkaplan = R.drawable.sunset;
            break;
        case 7:
            sonucArkaplan = R.drawable.sunset2;
            break;
        case 8:
            sonucArkaplan = R.drawable.wai;
            break;
        case 9:
            sonucArkaplan = R.drawable.water;
            break;
        case 10:
            sonucArkaplan = R.drawable.waterfall;
            break;
    }
    return sonucArkaplan;
}
```

And here is how i use it in my main activity:

```
 LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
 linearLayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(arkaplanGenerator.arkaplan()));
```

Those images are in drawable folder.Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's almost impossible to help you without information on which devices you have problem and which exactly problems you have (stack trace?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method getDrawable from the `Resources` class has been deprecated. You should use the one from `ContextCompat`:

```
linearLayout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),arkaplanGenerator.arkaplan()));
```

Comment: No sure this was the issue. Deprecated doesn't mean not working.